# PHP extract src from JavaScript string

Tags: php, regex

In my code I am trying to extract `src` value from JavaScript variable but I am literary confused because I have two `src` values JavaScript so I am using `explode` function but it doesn't extract the `url` properly. My main goal is to get only `.mp4` url from it but I don't how to extract it. I have no problem to use regex because it simple and short but I don't know how to use for it.

Here is the my PHP Code

```
$b = "var myVideo=videojs('my_play');myVideo.src([{type:\"video/mp4\",src:\"https://example.com/dl/abc123/video.mp4\"}])";
$data = explode('type:"video/mp4",src:"', $b);
echo $data[1];
```

Echo show this value

```
https://example.com/dl/abc123/video.mp4"}])
```

**Expected output:**

```
https://example.com/dl/abc123/video.mp4
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: see my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are using `preg_match` to achieve desired output.

**Regex:** `/src\s*:\s*"\K[^"]+`

> **1.** `src\s*:\s*"\K` this will match `src:"` and `\K` will reset current match. Optionally we are taking care of spaces with `\s*`
>
> **2.** `[^"]+` This will match all except `"`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/863205)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$b = "var myVideo=videojs('my_play');myVideo.src([{type:\"video/mp4\",src:\"https://example.com/dl/abc123/video.mp4\"}])";
preg_match('/src\s*:\s*"\K[^"]+/', $b,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: @Rtra Glad to help you my friend.. :)